# Show name of the current open website in any browser using python code

Tags: python, timer

I have been working on a python code which shows the time spent on an applicaton based on keyboard and mouse movement.
I can set the start and stop time, the output of this code is the duration I spend on each application in the set duration.
I have also added "idle time" which happens when I am not working on the system.

My question is,
In case I am using a browser app like chrome or firefox or others, I need the name of the website.
This will help me track how much time I am spenting on those websites

Answer (score 0):

You should 100% use Selenium. It's a browser automation tool that uses python to automate web browsers. I personally use it to automate YouTube uploads. You can do what your trying to do with a few commands, selenium is one of the best tools for this usecase!

Here's the github! - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you please suggest me libraries in particular..? or give an idea how to go about it..?

Comment: Selenium is a library. Use "pip install selenium" to use it. There should be a tutorial on how to open a website using it. It's pretty simple.